# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:0 cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'applicationprofileid' in select clause

Tags: sql, hive

```
create table sandbox_p_measurable_security.temp_calc_myaccess_privilegeddata1
stored as parquet as (
    select 
        applicationprofileid, 
        'OneBridge' as 'IsOnebridge' 
    from bigdata_normalized.myaccess_tblapplicationprofile apro
    where apro.applicationprofileid in (
        select apd.applicationprofileid 
        from bigdata_normalized.myaccess_tblapplicationprofiledependencies apd
        inner join bigdata_normalized.myaccess_tblsecuritygroup sg 
            on sg.securitygroupid = apd.securitygroupid
        where sg.businessrefcde = 'CDSOneBridge'
    )
);
```

Comment: Started working in hive hadoop environment for my SQL querries and struggling a bit. Whats is wrong with this query that I am running into the error above

Comment: Can you try to remove the single quotes around column alias `IsOnebridge`, like: `'OneBridge' as IsOnebridge`?

Comment: It still failed. Same error code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to ge the same error as you got and it got resolved after removing the round bracket `(` you have used after `stored as parquet as`

**Test Results:**

*Failure:*

```
Create table customers1
as (select * from customers)
```

Error as:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:3 cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' '*' in select clause
```

*Success:*

```
Create table customers1
as select * from customers
```

```
 Success.
```

Try running the query as below (Removed the round brackets)

```
create table sandbox_p_measurable_security.temp_calc_myaccess_privilegeddata1
as
    select 
        applicationprofileid, 
        'OneBridge' as 'IsOnebridge' 
    from bigdata_normalized.myaccess_tblapplicationprofile apro
    where apro.applicationprofileid in (
        select apd.applicationprofileid 
        from bigdata_normalized.myaccess_tblapplicationprofiledependencies apd
        inner join bigdata_normalized.myaccess_tblsecuritygroup sg 
            on sg.securitygroupid = apd.securitygroupid
        where sg.businessrefcde = 'CDSOneBridge')
stored as parquet;
```

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as Solved so that it would be helpful for others as well.